# Passing button image data between View Controllers Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uibutton

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple hours now.

I'm trying have a button with an image on my first VC, when clicked on, opens another VC with the same image enlarged. This is what I've got so far.

How the images are stored initially, its just a 4x3 buttons of images from xcassets :

```
 for case let hstack as UIStackView in stack.arrangedSubviews {
        for case let btn as UIButton in hstack.arrangedSubviews {
            let thisIMG = UIImage(named: randArray[k])
            k = k + 1


            btn.setImage(thisIMG, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            btn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        }
    }
```

And here is my prepare function, where test color/text were just to make sure I was doing part of the segue correctly:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let dest = segue.destination as? ImageViewController
    let button = sender as? UIButton

    dest?.imgFromFirst = button?.currentImage
    //dest?.testColor = .red
    //dest?.testText = "green eggs and ham"
 }
```

In the second View Controller I have the following:

```
var imgFromFirst: UIImage!
var testText = "this is not changing"
var testColor: UIColor!

@IBOutlet weak var enlargedImage: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //enlargedImage.setTitle(testText, for: .normal)
    //enlargedImage.backgroundColor = testColor

    enlargedImage.setImage(imgFromFirst, for: .normal)
    //enlargedImage.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
```

I can change the color, and the text of the button, but no luck on the image so far. I think I may be trying to access something that doesn't exist? So imgFromFirst is getting passed nothing, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At line `dest?.imgFromFirst = button?.currentImage`, you can replace by this:

```
dest?.imgFromFirst = button?.image(for: .normal)
```

or this `dest?.imgFromFirst = button?.imageView?.image`

Comment: Tried all your suggestions, unfortunately hasn't fixed my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

`func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` is calling when user tapping on the button. The current state of the button is `highlighted`, because user's finger on the button and button at this time is highlighted. 
To get an image, I need call `button?.image(for: .normal)` because you've set an image for button normal state.

Comment: I tried the dest?.imgFromFirst = button?.image(for: .normal) suggestion, still have nothing appearing the the 2nd VC